# Why do we exclude fruit and vegetables?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, vegetables

We see in Vayikra, chapter 11, lists of kosher animals (land, water, and flying), but I don't see any mention of vegetables? Why did the Torah leave out vegetables when it speaks of kashrut?

Comment: yamin, although you refer to koshering, which usually means the process of rendering an animal carcass kosher, you also refer to lists of animals, and I took your question to be about the latter. That question [has been answered already](/q/10616/), and you can read answers there. If, on the other hand, you meant to ask about rendering carcasses (or reaped plants) kosher, then please [edit] the question to clarify the connection to Leviticus 11's lists.

Comment: @Yamin, I'm assuming you're the original asker of this question on the cooking site? If so: Thanks for your recent edit, as that edit clarifies your intent in asking this question: you really mean to ask why some animal species but no vegetable species are non-kosher. You should be glad to see the answers at [the preexisting question](/q/10616), then. Please [edit] the question further to distinguish it from that one if your intent isn't the same as that one.